# Wso2 msf4j- metrics and http monitoring example not run on macos

Tags: wso2, msf4j

I am training myself in examples of wso2 msf4j. Concretely is example in the following link:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/MSF4J100/Using+Metrics+and+HTTP+Monitoring+Interceptors#UsingMetricsandHTTPMonitoringInterceptors-ConfiguringDAStoreceivemetrics

I have done as described in documentation, but I couldn't see metrics in dashboard (please see the attachment).

[image]

Could anyone please help me to address this issue.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually view your own Metrics in the WSO2 DAS Metrics page. That page shows the Metrics used by the WSO2 DAS.

For MSF4J Metrics, there is no dashboard. The MSF4J Metrics allows you to publish Metric events to WSO2 DAS.

In WSO2 DAS, you can create a dashboard to visualize your data. Please see [WSO2 DAS documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Communicating+Results)